# any issue with enable_partitionwise_join at instance level

Tags: postgresql

while running aggregate queries on partitioned table there is improvement when enable_partitionwise_join is turned on. By default this parameter is disabled and going by the documentation it says (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-query.html)

> Because partitionwise grouping or aggregation can use significantly more CPU time and memory during planning, the default is off.

Why would it take "significantly" more CPU and memory for the planner? Is there any foreseeable issues when enabling this at the instance level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing dangerous about this parameter.

It is just that only very specific queries benefit from this: the tables need to be partitioned identically, and the partitioning key must be part of the join condition.

Enabling the parameter slightly increases query planning time for many queries, but only few benefit. That is the reason this is disabled by default. The problem is exacerbated because PostgreSQL usually doesn't cache query plans (you'd have to use prepared statements or PL/pgSQL functions).